# Why can I only open one folder at a time in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.10

In Ubuntu 11.10, is there any reason why I can only open one folder at a time via the GUI?

I click home folder, navigate to the folder I want to go to, then I hit home folder again to bring up another home folder and nothing opens. I'm so confused about the laptops I can do this on. I can do this on Work PC's, but not on this PC however.

Comment: Where are you clicking? If you are using the Unity launcher, you can middle-click any icon to open a new window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Middle Clicking on any item in the Launcher in Ubuntu Unity will open a new instance of that Application.

Comment: Question that worked swimmingly on my desktop, however. What If I am on my laptop and only have the built in mouse that has no middle clicking device?

Answer (score 2):

Shift + Double click, or right click on "Home" in breadcrumb and select "Open in New Window".